# Neos CMS: Extending page properties for the backend

Tags: neoscms

Is it possible to have a checkbox in the Neos backend for every page to show/hide some HTML and JavaScript code in the page (and even better also for all sub pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add anew property for `Neos.Neos:Document` or create a new type and then attach it as `superType` to every page type you want.

Sample settings for `Neos.Neos:Document`:

```
'Neos.Neos:Document':
  ui:
    inspector:
      groups:
        globalsettings:
          label: 'My special settings'
          tab: 'default'
  properties:
    yourVariableName:
      type: boolean
      defaultValue: false
      ui:
        label: 'Hide content'
        reloadPageIfChanged: FALSE
        inspector:
          position: 10
          group: 'globalsettings'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the current or parent page has a selected value you can do this with Fusion:

```
nodeOrParentNodeIsChecked = ${q(node).closest('[instanceof Neos.Neos:Document][yourVariableName]').property('yourVariableName')}
```

Fell free to ask on https://discuss.neos.io, because this is our official forum. You'll find more information here: https://www.neos.io/docs-and-support/support.html

Comment: Thank you for this supplement! It helped me a lot. Also thanks for the links. I didn't know there is an official forum for such questions.

One last question. Is there a clearer way to hide/show some lines of code in my Default.html template instead of this:

`{f:if(condition: '{nodeOrParentNodeIsChecked}', then: 'Show disclaimer code')}`